# MS Word Macro to change string to Numbers in long documents?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros, string

I am as beginner as it gets with VBA and macro. I am looking to record a macro for MS Word documents that converts string to number. For example the document will have like (one thousand and four) or (twenty six percent) or page (sixty two).

Is there a way to create a macro that will change these to 1004 (or 1,004), 26 percent (or 26% doesn't matter) and 62. Etc...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What research have you done? The biggest challenge I see is how the macro will know what `text` to convert to a number. It does not recognize the text "*sixty two*" as a number. It sees it as two words.

Comment: Yes I figured that would be a problem and I have done some research but don't understand much of it. The problem is that the documents have a huge amount of references to numbers that are spelled out as text and it would save a huge amount of time to just be able to read through with 14,302 instead of fourteen thousand three hundred and two, etc. So this is what I'm looking to solve...

Comment: 1. Have any/all of these numbers been generated using a field code? (For example, in Word, you can use { QUOTE "1234" \*cardtext } to insert "one thousand two hundred thirty-four" ? (You can see toggle between "field code" and "field result" view using Alt-F9). My guess is that they have not, but if they have, you might be able to leverage that fact. 2. How consistent are the "text numbers" ? (e.g. do you see "fourteen thousand three hundred and two" *and* "fourteen thousand, three hundred and two" etc.?). 3. How many numbers do you think are in there?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project and challenge. Off-topic in this form here though.

Comment: The other that *one* may face in this situation is what happens if the number has another meaning... You only have 10 numbers (zero, one, two... nine, ten), and then the concept of the tens (thirty, fourty) and then then the terms hundred, thousand etc... It would be a question of mapping the number based upon the number of digits of the number